# Sending image from b4a client to Delphi server

Tags: sockets, delphi, send

I want to send images from a b4a client to a server in Delphi. When sending 76k I receive just 6k.

My code is as follows:

b4a code

```vb
If Successful Then
  astream.Initialize(socket.InputStream,socket.OutputStream,"astream")
  ' astream.InitializePrefix(socket.InputStream,True,socket.OutputStream,"astream")
End If

Private Sub astream_NewData (Buffer() As Byte)
  If File.Exists(File.DirRootExternal, "Pictures/1.jpg") Then
    Dim Data() As Byte=Bit.InputStreamToBytes(File.OpenInput(File.DirRootExternal, "Pictures/1.jpg")) ' jpg 156 Ko
    If astream.Write(Data) Then
      Log(Data.Length)
    End If
  Else
    Log("File Not Found")
  End If
End Sub
```

Delphi code

```pascal
procedure TForm1.serverClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  Stream: TStringStream;
begin
  Stream := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    Stream.Position := 0;
    Stream.WriteString(Socket.ReceiveText);
    Stream.SaveToFile('D:\Received.jpg'); //jpg Received  6,66 Ko
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is a common issue. The read event (`serverClientRead` in your code) is, potentially, called multiple times. Each time it is called, data is to be appended. You need to therefore allow the reader to know when all parts of the transmission have been received. You also need to stop using `ReceiveText` and `WriteString`. This is binary data.

Comment: Thank you Mr Remy , Have you  an example To read it as binary in this case ?

Comment: You'd be able to work this out yourself by reading the documentation

Comment: thank's i test with folowing code receive  uncomplete stream                              [code]Size := Socket.ReceiveLength;
  Socket.ReceiveBuf(Bytes, Size);[/code]

Comment: Yes. Did you read my first comment about the data arriving in multiple calls of your event handler, and you then having to piece it together?

Comment: Have you an Example Please ?

Comment: Websearch will find plenty.

Comment: Now I can Get all image Data But the image is corrupted

My code is

       Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
         Size := Socket.ReceiveLength;
        Socket.ReceiveBuf(b, Size);
        Stream.Write(b,sizeof(b));
        Stream.SaveToFile('D\Received.jpg');
        stream.Free;

Comment: You probably aren't receiving all the data. You still aren't heeding the advice I gave you in the first comment. Do you understand that the event is called multiple times?